# IIS web requests are hanging indefinitely - OWIN module

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin

A web app (ASP .NET MVC - C#) works on a windows machine and it is hosted already on IIS 8.5. The app uses [Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.membership) along with .NET framework 4.5.

Recently, it went down twice upon the total response time reached more than 1 million milliseconds.

I have checked the IIS Worker Process and I saw all requests are stuck there as per the below screenshot in `PreExecuteRequestHeaders` in `OWIN` module, the application has no changes since too long time ago, and the traffic is not high.

I can see there is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33256407/owin-on-iis-web-requests-hang-indefinitely) which had the same issue, but the problem here I wanna know why or what is the root cause of the issue? Because, I am not using `async` calls in this application.

[image: IIS - PreExecuteRequestHeaders]

**EDIT**:
I am using the blow in the startup:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]
namespace MyProject
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // some other configurations which are related to logs ... bla bla bla
        }
    }
}

public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
        // Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @mjwills I wish I could reproduce the case again, I just had been reported with the issue after getting the app completely down!

Comment: If you cannot reproduce the issue, then there is nothing to discuss. Actual troubleshooting requires it to happen again, and then effective measures can be taken, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/10/16/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough/